# Why won't the value of my int change?

Tags: java

Hi I'm fairly new to java and I am working on code that works as a calendar. I thought I had completed it but the days seem to remain as 31 rather than changing based on the if/else statement. Here is the code:

```
public int maxDaysInMonth( int year, int month )
{

boolean A = (year % 4 == 0) || ((year%4==0) && (year % 100 != 0));

int days = 0;
int iMonth = 0;

 if( iMonth == 4 || iMonth == 6 || iMonth == 9 || iMonth == 11)
{
    days = 30;
}

else if ( iMonth == 1 || iMonth == 3 || iMonth == 5 || iMonth == 7 || iMonth == 8 || iMonth == 10 || iMonth == 12)
{
    days = 31;
}

if (A == true && iMonth == 2)
{ 
    days = 29; 
}
else if (A == false && iMonth == 2)
{
    days = 28;
}

return days;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you missing `iMonth = month ` assignment

Comment: Or just eliminate `iMonth` and use `month` instead.

Comment: This is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with using a debugger.  With a Java debugger you can step through the code line-by-line as it executes and observe the runtime values and behavior.  This will allow you to determine if your logic is working as expected, and find specifically where it does what you don't expect.  You can see the runtime values when that happens.  Which is great information for you to use to diagnose the problem, as well as for us to use to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of `iMonth`?  You initialize it to `0` then test it as if it already represented a month.

You don't need `iMonth`; just use `month` in your `if` tests.

Also, your leap year determination isn't quite correct.  It's always a leap year if the year number is divisible by `400`.  Try

```
boolean A = (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0));
```

You also might want a more descriptive variable name, such as `isALeapYear`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The leap year information was useful too :)

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solutions:**

**1.** Replace all `iMonth` with `month` - the variable you provided by method parameter.

**2.** Call the `maxDaysInMonth( int year, int month )` method like this -

```
maxDaysInMonth( 2015, 1); // for January  
maxDaysInMonth( 2015, 2); // for February
maxDaysInMonth( 2015, 11); //for December
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other has mentioned your problem is with `iMonth`

Try using a simple similar code :

```
public int maxDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    int days;
    switch (month) {
        case 2:
            boolean A = (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0));
            days = A ? 29 : 28;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            days = 30;
            break;
        default:
            days = 31;
    }
    return days;
}
```